# view positioning in android

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview

I have a `scrollView` at the bottom of my screen (the light blue area with a triangle)

[image]

I have code that scrolls this view:

```
        HorizontalScrollView sv=(HorizontalScrollView)button.getParent().getParent();
        int offsetX=getButtonXPosition()-sv.getWidth()/2;
        sv.smoothScrollTo(offsetX, 0);
```

I try to understand the `view positioning in android` through this line:

`sv.smoothScrollTo(offsetX, 0);`

Does it make sense? it the left upper corner of this view is on coordinate (0,0)

otherwise the y coordiante would have been `!= 0`

and if so, is it for any view? meaning the whole positioning is relative

and nor absolute with regards the whole screen ?

Comment: X axis from left to right. Y axis is from top to bottom. (0,0) of a View is its top left corner.

Comment: @S.D. so there is no coordinate grid regarding the whole screen?

Comment: No. Each View has its own. But you can use `(getLeft() + getRight())/2` of `Button` view, to get its horizontal center in terms of parent view's co-ordinated.

Comment: You have the `getLocationOnScreen()` or `getLocationInWindow()` methods to obtain coordinates relative to the screen.